# Android Universal Image Loader in Listview from hashmap

Tags: java, android, image, listview, universal-image-loader

I would like to add image from my `URL` to the `ImageView` inside `ListView` item.

I'm using `Android Universal Image Loader`: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

And here's how my code looks like right now:

```
protected  void onPostExecute(JSONObject objdanejson){
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            android = objdanejson.getJSONArray(TAG_ZAWARTOSC);
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                final String akt_tytul = c.getString(TAG_TYTUL);
                final String akt_skrot = c.getString(TAG_SKROT);
                final String akt_tresc = c.getString(TAG_TRESC);
                final String akt_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                final String akt_IMG = c.getString(TAG_IMG);



                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_TYTUL, akt_tytul);
                map.put(TAG_SKROT, akt_skrot);
                map.put(TAG_ID, akt_id);
                map.put(TAG_TRESC, akt_tresc);
                map.put(TAG_IMG, akt_IMG);



                oslist.add(map);
                lista_aktualnosci = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_aktualnosci);

                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(aktualnosci.this, oslist,
                      R.layout.aktualnosc_item,
                        new String[]{TAG_TYTUL, TAG_SKROT}, new int[]{R.id.aktTytul, R.id.aktSkrot});
                lista_aktualnosci.setAdapter(adapter);


                lista_aktualnosci.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(aktualnosci.this, "Kliknąłeś na " + oslist.get(+position).get("akt_tytul"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Intent czytaj = new Intent(aktualnosci.this, aktualnosc_czytaj.class);



                            czytaj.putExtra("tytuł",oslist.get(+position).get("akt_tytul"));
                            czytaj.putExtra("tresc",oslist.get(+position).get("akt_tresc"));
                            czytaj.putExtra("id",oslist.get(+position).get("akt_id"));
                            startActivity(czytaj);
                        }
                });


            }
        }
         catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

For now it downloads text, but I want to use url that is in **TAG_IMG** with image loader function to display in in `ImageView` inside `ListView` item.

Anyone know how to do it?
Also I think I will need to add main URL to img url, for it to work, so any help will be much appreciated.